# Stop Mouse Cursor from Moving Horizontally, but still want to capture MouseMove Events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, cursor

In my winforms app, I have a feature that opens a dropdown menu, and you move your cursor left or right to select a sub-option. But, I don't want the cursor to move, I just want the sub-options them selves to move left or right (depending on which direction the mouse is trying to move in). I hope this makes sense to you.

Does anyone know how to stop the cursor from moving in a particular direction, while still being able to capture mousemove events while the user "moves" the mouse?

Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not try to implement this, as it breaks all user interface standards and will just confuse the user. It's not up to your application to decide where the mouse should be able to move. If you want to implement some other way of allowing navigation selection then I would suggest investigating other options.

Comment: This feature was requested by my client.

Comment: Then as an experienced developer it's your job to convince him that it's a very bad idea, why it's a bad idea, and to present some alternatives which follow best practise. You're the professional, that's why they're the client.

Comment: I understand that and I agree to an extent. "Best" practices aside though, I really don't see why this particular idea is bad practice. I've got it implemented now, and my thoughts on it are, 1: Customer wants it, 2: It looks really cool and blends in well with the interface, 3: It works and 4: It requires less hand movement to navigate through the horizontal menu. Could you explain why it's bad practice for this? I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: Firstly, glad you managed to achieve what you want to do. As to why it's a bad idea, well mostly because the mouse is part of the overall operating system and not just for your app. Your application should not interfere with the way global objects behave as it provides an inconsistent approach for the user. Secondly if your app crashed and you had implemented some kind of hooking or restriction on the mouse then that could affect the rest of the operating system. As to what clients want, I think it's the job of the developer to advise and inform as well as develop: http://clientsfromhell.net/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should implement such a solution at all.

But well, you could set the mouse cursor position back to its original position within the MouseMove Handler. But you have to remove the handler before setting back the position and adding them again after this. You can set the Mouse position via pInvoke. How to do that, you can find here http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

Comment: Thanks @DanielB.. Checking link out now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set Cursor position manualy

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(400,400);
        Console.WriteLine("fired");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stecya, I did think of that but I guess I just thought there would be a more um.. I dunno, a more proper way to do it? But then again I don't see why this way wouldn't be proper either.. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it that easy? Why did I use pInvoke for that always oO

Comment: Yeah :) But um, maybe in different Win OS versions it might not be that easy??? There must be a reason you had to use pInvoke :)